# How to capture Chrome's native HTML 5 Video/Audio player's download control click?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, html5-video, html5-audio

Does anyone happen to know how to capture the event and/or click event with JavaScript for the user actually choosing to download the media in Chrome's native HTML 5 media player?

In newer versions of Chrome there is a native browser HTML 5 Audio/Video player control that allows the user to download the media (I know this applies to at least Version 55.0.2883.87).

The answer for this could involve some kind of Shadow DOM trickery.

```
<audio preload="none" controls="true" src="file.mp3"></audio>
```

[image: Chrome HTML5 Media Player with Controls Enabled]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if HTML5 video player has any native event where it can capture start of download but it has stalled | onstalled event which Occurs when the download has stopped.

```
video.addEventListener("stalled", function () {
  alert("Download was stalled");
}, false);
```